# Looping through media items

Tags: java, android, media

I wanted to make an area in the app that will get a `json` of media items, whether they are video or images or even plain text, and it will loop through all the media one by one, in the same spot.

If I'll pick an `ImageView` so I can display only images, so as if I pick `TextView` or `VideoView`.

How can I achieve that?

Example Json:

```
{
 "1": {
    "type": "img",
    "content": "xyz.jpg",
    "duration": "10"
  },
  "2": {
    "type": "video",
    "content": "abc.mp4",
    "duration": "34"
  },
  "3": {
    "type": "text",
    "content": "Welcome to my Digitial Signage Screen",
    "duration": "54"
  },
  "4": {
    "type": "video",
    "content": "efg.mp4",
    "duration": "22"
  },
}
```

I want to loop and check the media type every time, if it's an "`img`" type to display the image for the duration written, if it's a text type so write the text for the duration given, and so on.

Comment: I think you need to add an example JSON.

Comment: @TungDuong added the json example mate

Comment: so will you show those data on a RecyclerView or ListView ?